# Combining Firebase Firestore query results in Firestore Functions before sending email

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having several issues wrapping my head around promises. This time I'm trying to combine 4 Firestore queries into one and validating if any of those queries returns a result, if it does, I want to throw an error to the user, if not I want to proceed into sending the email and storing it's data.

How do I wait/combine the queries and validate the results?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
export const sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req: functions.Request, res: functions.Response) => {
  const { name, email, doc, state, city, phone, msg, } = req.body

  var dbPromises = [];

  const ip1 = req.headers["fastly-client-ip"]
  dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('messages').where('ip1', '==', ip1).get())

  const ip2 = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]
  dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('messages').where('ip2', '==', ip2).get())

  dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('messages').where('email', '==', email).get())

  dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('blocked-emails').where('email', '==', email).get())

  Promise.all(dbPromises)
    .then(() => {
      // TODO validate if there is any result > 0, if any, throw error to the user, else continue into sending the email
    });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `"${name}" <${email}>`,
    to: 'a_email@gmail.com',
    replyTo: `"${name}" <${email}>`,
    subject: `Contact - ${name}`,
    html: `<div>${name}</div>
           <div>${email}</div>
           <div>${doc}</div>
           <div>${state}</div>
           <div>${city}</div>
           <div>${phone}</div>
           <div>${msg}</div>`,
  }

  cors()(req, res, () => {
    transport
      .sendMail(mailOptions)
      .then(() => {
        firestore
          .collection('messages')
          .add({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            doc: doc,
            state: state,
            city: city,
            phone: phone,
            msg: msg,
            ip1: ip1,
            ip2: ip2,
          })
          .then(() => {
            return res.status(201).send()
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Internal error.', error)
        return res.status(500).send()
      })
  })

})
```

How to really combine and check if any result is > 0, returning an error to the user?

Comment: Your onRequest Handler needs to return a Promise.  Inside of your promises, you need to either return another promise (such as `firestore.collect.add(...`) or return the completed data.  Don't nest `.then` blocks inside of other `.then` blocks.  To me, it looks like most of what you want to do can be better served by Promises.  RxJS is great, don't get me wrong, but I'm not certain this is the right tool for what you want.

Comment: Also, where are you subscribing to the streams? Hmm... let me look at this in a better editor....

Comment: I'm very new to Promisses/Observables, sorry about that. I'm trying to remove the little usage that RxJS has in the code, but I can't wrap my head aroung all the nesting hell, await async and this new paradigm. I just want to know if the user is in the database or not and then send the email.

Comment: @JamesPoag I've changed my code, if you could take a look at it again I would be thankfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I was able to come up with.  I fired this up in a debugger to step through and make sure everything works.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors');

// Needed this to connect to Firestore, my code not yours
admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

// Emulate the transport.sendMail() for debug purposes
let transport = {
    sendMail: (options) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Sending Mail: ${options}`);
            resolve(options);
        });
    }
}

module.exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    if (req.method !== 'POST') // won't have a body
        return res.status(400).send(`Error: ${req.method} is not Accepted.`);

    // extract params from body
    const { name, email, doc, state, city, phone, msg, } = req.body

    let dbPromises = [];
    let firestore = admin.firestore(); // alias to lineup with OP's code

    // extract headers
    const ip1 = req.headers["fastly-client-ip"];
    const ip2 = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"];

    // validate input, if bad: emit Client error
    if (!ip1 || !ip2 || !email)
        return res.status(400).send("Error: Invalid Request.");

    // query previous message existence
    dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('messages').where('ip1', '==', ip1).get());
    dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('messages').where('ip2', '==', ip2).get())
    dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('messages').where('email', '==', email).get())
    dbPromises.push(firestore.collection('blocked-emails').where('email', '==', email).get())

    // Need to return a promise so your function doesn't timeout
    return Promise.all(dbPromises)
        .then(resultDocs => {
            if (resultDocs.length !== 4)
                throw new Error("Programmer Error");

            // validate if there is any result > 0, if any, throw error to the user
            if (resultDocs[0] !== null && resultDocs[0].docs.length !== 0)
                throw new Error(`${ip1} already exists`);
            if (resultDocs[1] !== null && resultDocs[1].docs.length !== 0)
                throw new Error(`${ip2} already exists`);
            if (resultDocs[2] !== null && resultDocs[2].docs.length !== 0)
                throw new Error(`${email} already exists`);
            if (resultDocs[3] !== null && resultDocs[3].docs.length !== 0)
                throw new Error(`${email} is blocked`);

            return null;
        })
        .then(() => {
            // Build message for mailer
            const mailOptions = {
                from: `"${name}" <${email}>`,
                to: 'a_email@gmail.com',
                replyTo: `"${name}" <${email}>`,
                subject: `Contact - ${name}`,
                html: `<div>${name}</div>
                     <div>${email}</div>
                     <div>${doc}</div>
                     <div>${state}</div>
                     <div>${city}</div>
                     <div>${phone}</div>
                     <div>${msg}</div>`,
            }

            let innerPromise = null;

            // Fix headers for cross-origin
            cors()(req, res, () => {
                // send mail returns a promise
                innerPromise = transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
            });

            return innerPromise; // return promise or null
        })
        .then(sendMailResult => {

            if (!sendMailResult) {
                // not sure if transport.sendMail even returns result
                // do validation here if yes
            }

            // write message to store
            return firestore
                .collection('messages')
                .add({
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    doc: doc,
                    state: state,
                    city: city,
                    phone: phone,
                    msg: msg,
                    ip1: ip1,
                    ip2: ip2,
                });
        })
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(201).send("Success")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(String(err));
        })
})
```

The main take-away is how the promises are structured: always return finished data or another promise from inside, and chain them together using `.then`.  The main function should also return a promise, so that the cloud-function doesn't time-out before everything completes.

Comment: Beautiful code. Thanks a lot for your help. Many examples, comments and very well organized!